# Can I set a default value for field.types when using dbWriteTable?

Tags: r, sql-server

I'm trying to write a dataframe to SQL Server using the following line

```
dbWriteTable(conn,"r_test_upload",df, field.types = c(longnotes ="varchar(max)"))
```

By default it's trying to upload all my fields as `varchar(255)`, which is too short. I can manually specify the columns but I don't want to do that. I want it to assume `varchar(max)` unless I tell it otherwise.

I also tried

```
dbWriteTable(con,"r_test_upload2",result_csv, field.types = c(.default ="varchar(max)"))
```

but it assumed that was a field name and failed with the following:

> Error: Columns in `field.types` must be in the input, missing columns:
>     - '.default'

I'll also take any other package suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `dbWriteTable` function is implemented individually in each driver package (e.g., `RSQLite`, `odbc`), so the answer technically depends on that ... but I think the end-result will be the same: you'll need to use a wrapper function.

Looking at the `odbc` package, we find that `dbWriteTable` (really, [`odbc_write_table`](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/blob/8c095067aeff4088aec6871e17fd3f66122c217c/R/Table.R#L30)) only uses `field.types` if a new table must be created, for which it calls [`sqlCreateTable`](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/blob/8c095067aeff4088aec6871e17fd3f66122c217c/R/Table.R#L143). That calls [`createFields`](https://github.com/r-dbi/odbc/blob/8c095067aeff4088aec6871e17fd3f66122c217c/R/Table.R#L152), which in this package appears to have strict requirements of names.

To do what you want, you'll probably need a wrapper function:

```r
my_dbWriteTable <- function(conn, name, value, ..., field.types = NULL) {
  cl <- match.call(expand.dots = TRUE)
  cl[[1]] <- substitute(dbWriteTable)
  if (!is.null(field.types) && ".default" %in% names(field.types)) {
    othernames <- setdiff(colnames(value), names(field.types))
    cl$field.types <- c(
      field.types[ setdiff(names(field.types), ".default") ],
      setNames(rep(field.types[".default"], length(othernames)), othernames)
    )
  }
  eval.parent(cl)
}

my_dbWriteTable(con, "quux", mtcars, field.types=c(cyl="integer", .default="varchar(max)"))
DBI::dbGetQuery(con, "select column_name, data_type from information_schema.columns where table_name='quux'")
#    column_name data_type
# 1    row_names   varchar
# 2          mpg   varchar
# 3          cyl       int
# 4         disp   varchar
# 5           hp   varchar
# 6         drat   varchar
# 7           wt   varchar
# 8         qsec   varchar
# 9           vs   varchar
# 10          am   varchar
# 11        gear   varchar
# 12        carb   varchar
```

(This approach assumes that some form of `dbWriteTable` is visible/available from the calling environment.)

Comment: Not only did this wrapper work, it's still part of my toolbox a year and a half later ;)
Just thought I'd let you know.

Comment: That's awesome! Thanks for the super-positive feedback, @twodimes!